# Understanding why any permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ has a cyclid decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, cyclic-groups, cyclic-decomposition

Consider the first theorem presented [here](https://planetmath.org/conjugacyclassesinthesymmetricgroupsn) which proves that any permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ has a cyclic decomposition. As I've understood from the given proof, it is stated that $\sigma \in S_n$ has a cyclic decomposition because the size of the orbit of a given $x$ is $d$, where $d$ is the order of the permutation $\sigma$. As saddening as it may sound, I'm completely missing the crux of the proof as I don't understand why the fact that the size of the orbit of some $x$ is equal to the size of the permutation $\sigma$ means that this cyclic representation of the orbit of $x$ "decomposes" the permutation $\sigma$. I.e. why do we have a cyclic decomposition for the arbitrary permutation $\sigma$?

Comment: The idea is: decomposition in orbits exists, and each orbit gives a cycle. Note that $d$ is not the order of $\sigma$, but the order of the class of $\sigma$ in $G/G_x$ where $G=\langle \sigma\rangle$. This being said, I don't think it's a very good proof for a beginner. Try to find a proof in another source, maybe?